# Converting WMI from vbscript to powershell

Tags: iis, powershell, wmi, vbscript

I'm trying to follow the guides for accessing IIS 6 using WMI but I'm having trouble working out how to translate the [Get method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393868(v=vs.85).aspx) of SWbemServices as Get-WmiObject doesn't seem to use the same path syntax ([Describing the Location of a WMI Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390350(v=vs.85).aspx)).

The example I was following is located on [Connecting to the WMI Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525808(v=vs.90).aspx):

```
' Method 1
set locatorObj = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator") 
set providerObj = locatorObj.ConnectServer("MyMachine", "root/MicrosoftIISv2") 
set nodeObj = providerObj.Get("IIsWebVirtualDir='W3SVC/1/Root'") 

' Method 2
set providerObj = GetObject("winmgmts://MyMachine/root/MicrosoftIISv2") 
set nodeObj = providerObj.get("IIsWebVirtualDir='W3SVC/1/ROOT'") 

' Method 3
set nodeObj = GetObject("winmgmts://MyMachine/root/MicrosoftIISv2:IIsWebVirtualDir='W3SVC/1/ROOT'")
```

Answer (score 4):

This first depends upon whether the string refers to an object or a class.
For objects; you can cast the string to `wmi`.
For classes; you can cast the string to `wmiclass`.

```
[wmi] 'root\MicrosoftIISv2:IIsWebVirtualDir="W3SVC/1/ROOT"'
[wmiclass] 'root\MicrosoftIISv2:IIsWebVirtualDir'
```

Some method names in WMI might be changed from their wsh names, eg `SpawnInstance_` is now `CreateInstance` and `Put_` is just `Put`.

wmi is an alias for [System.Management.ManagementObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Management.ManagementObject).
wmiclass is an alias for [System.Management.ManagementClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Management.ManagementClass)

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261237/creating-an-iis-6-0-application-pool-using-powershell/264404#264404 for an example.